# Scope <style> tag's selectors inside markup of text field created by WYSIWYG editor in Django

Tags: html, css, django, wysiwyg

I have Django website with django-summernote WYSIWYG editor. Admin can add news. Editor is used for editing text fields of DB models using HTML markup. User can edit field in HTML source mode. So he can paste <style> tag inside. For example he can paste something like this:

```
<style>
p {
 color:red;
}
</style>
```

And of course after rendering field with this snippet in Django HTML template it will affect all next <p> tags, not only those which are inside field.
And this is the problem. I want to allow user use <style> tag inside markup but prevent it from affecting other parts of the page.
I know I can put markup in iframe but maybe there are other solutions. So I want to to know how should I do it.

P.S If there is another WYSIWYG editor lib for django which can scope style in some way  tell me.

Comment: Be aware that the scope attribtue has been deprectated a couple years ago (I believ 2013 while FF kept it alive witin FF until 2017). Unless a library allows it (in which case I'm unaware) there should be no legit way to do this. [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped)